# __dirname is not defined importing electron remote

Tags: vue.js, webpack, electron, electron-vue

I have a problem. I want to set up the minimize, maximize and close buttons on a frameless window but I can't due to this problem importing the electron remote. Thanks.

```
import { remote } from "electron";

 methods...

 closeWindow() {
  var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
  window.close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: you need to enable the nodeIntegration while you are creating browserWIndow

Comment: good, now I get "fs.existsSync is not a function" :/

Comment: `npm install fs --save`

Comment: installing fs does not fix this issue @tpikachu

Answer (score 0):

Just import it like that:

```
const { remote } = window.require('electron')
```

and after that your code:

```
methods...    
closeWindow() {
  remote.getCurrentWindow().close();
}
```